# How to organize s3 uploads client/server with AWS SDK

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a bucket that has multiple users, and would like to pre-sign urls for the client to upload to s3 (some files can be large, so I'd rather they not pass through the Node server. My question is this: Until the mongo database is hit, there is no mongo Object Id to tag as a prefix for the file. (I'm separating the files in this structure: (UserID/PostID/resource) so you can check all of a user's pictures by looking under /UserID, and you can target a specific post by also adding the PostID. Conversely, there is no Object URL until the client uploads the file, so I'm at a bit of an impasse.

Is it bad practice to rename files after they touch the bucket? I just can't pre-know the ObjectID (the post has to be created in Mongo first) - but the user has to select what files they want to upload before the object is created. I was thinking the best flow could be one of two situations:

1. Client sets files -> Mongo created Document -> Responds to client with ObjectID and pre-signed urls for each file with the key set to /UserID/PostID/name. After successful upload, it re-triggers an update function on the server to edit the urls of the post. after update, send success to client.
2. Client uploads files to root of bucket -> Mongo doc created where urls of uploaded s3 files are being stored -> iterate over list and prepend the UserID and newly-created PostID, updating mongo document -> success response to client

Is there another approach that I don't know about?

Answer (score 1):

Answering your question:

**Is it bad practice to rename files after they touch the server?**

If you are planing to use S3 to save your files, there is no server, so there is no problems to change these files after you upload them.

The only thing that you need to understand is renaming a object you need to two requests:

1. copy the object with a new name
2. delete the old object with the old name

And this means that maybe can be a problem in costs/latency if you have a huge number of changes (but I can say for most of cases this will not be a problem)

I can say that the first option will be a good option for you, and the only thing that I would change is adding a Serverless processing for your object/files, using the AWS Lambda service will be a good option .

In this case instead of updating the files on the server, you will update using a Lambda function, you only need to add a trigger for your bucket in the `PutObject` event on S3, this way will can change the name of your files in the best processing time for your client and with low costs.

Comment: I have an express backend that handles Mongo. It'll already be spun up and doing other work, so getting a presigned url isn't a big deal.

Comment: You do not need to change the presigned url  process, you can just send the rename process for Lambda Functions, this will make your process easier

Comment: I don't want a lambda function because of cold starts, and my node server is already doing work in the mongo database. Is it easy to rename, or does it really involve copying (some video files could be multiple GB). Seems like that'd add up.